# Scale values from a smaller array into a bigger array

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have an array, whose size is 256. This array has elements which are in 0 to 1 range. Now, i need an array whose size should be 65536, where each element should be interpolated or scaled from the original array of 256 values. I asked in another thread, but i wasnt clear enough :(

Some kind of mapping where, lets say, 10 values from the original image should match to more number values in the bigger array. Is it doable?

EDIT : lets say i have an array which is 256 floats, each float is in 0 to 1 range.  Now, i need a new array, which should be 65536 floats again each float in 0 to 1 range.  These new float values should be interpolated or scaled from original 256 floats.

Comment: Yes, it's doable. But until you make your problem more specific, you won't get any answers; as-is, this question will most likely be closed for the same reason your last one was.

Comment: As an idea: For your new array, index 384 lies halfway between the old array's indexes 1 and 2, so it should contain a correspondingly weighted average of those two. Now just generalize that.

Comment: Yes, something like bins, i have 256 bins, each with some float value in 0 to 1 range, but now, i need 65536 bins, where each bin should have an interpolated or scaled value from the old 256 bins

Comment: @ildjarn, this is exactly my question!, how should interpolate or scale these values!. Thanks!

Comment: @user933322 : No, that's begging the question. "How can I make foo into bar?" is not an answerable question; we don't know what output you want, so how could we know how to generate that output?

Comment: @ildjarn, i think the question is pretty clear

Comment: @I__ : Then by all means, answer it.

Comment: @ildj i dont know the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: My C++ isn't so great these days. This will look something more like Java. I'm assuming you weren't planning on copying and pasting anyway: knowing the algorithm is much more important then the implementation language.

The following algorithm does NOT make 65536 entries for a 256 entry input. Instead, it makes 65281. The reason for this is you need to scale FROM something TO something else. Consider a fence with 256 posts. You'll only have 255 sections of fence. Each scaling corresponds to a section of fence. For simple math, I make the number of samples between each original sample equal to the number of original samples. So if you put a 4 entry input, you'll get a 13 entry output. A 100 entry input will make a 9901 entry output.

Enjoy!

```
std::vector<double> sample(std::vector<double> orig) {

    std::vector<double> result(orig.size() * (orig.size() - 1) + 1);

    /* for each value, make that many values scaled between this and the last piece */
    for(int i = 0; i < orig.size() - 1; i++) {
        double last = orig[i];
        double curr = orig[i+1];
        double diff = curr - last;
        double step = diff / orig.size();
        int offset = i * orig.size();
        for(int j = 0; j < orig.size(); j++) {
            result[offset + j] = last + (step * j);
        }
    }
    result[result.size() - 1] = orig[orig.size() - 1];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a linear interpolation?

Comment: @Duck that should see a doctor about the mooing, yes that is a linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking about [sample rate conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_rate_conversion). How best to do that depends on the meaning of your data. For example if your array represented a sound wave, you must take care not to introduce harmonic distortion, which would happen if you used linear interpolation.

The [Wikipedia article on interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) should give you some starting points.

Comment: i believe what is he is asking is for a direct/non-skewed translation